# How to compare select options with database values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, cucumber, capybara

I have a class called State in my model and a states select (combo box) in my page. I need to create the step definition that compares the values in the database to the values in the combo box.

I've been able to find the combo box by its ID, but I couldn't find a way to compare each option.

```
expect(page.find_by_id('patient_state_id'))
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've been able to solve this with the following code:

```
Given(/^I am an application user$/) do
end

When(/^I display the patient registration form$/) do
  visit('/patients/new')
end

Then(/^I should be able see the list of registered states$/) do
  states = State.pluck(:description)

  page.find_by_id('patient_state_id').all('option').each do |el|
    expect(states).to include(el.text)
  end

end
```